# How to set Camera's preview as background to surfaceview in rajawali & capture screen with 3D Obj & Camera preview

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, camera, rajawali

I am new to Opengl and i am trying to use rajawali for my android app.

I am trying to render a 3D object and I want to show the 3D objects background as device's Camera's preview. I saw some result for achieving this but they suggested to use CameraView and add it to the content view.

But I also want to Capture the Screen along with the Camera preview and 3d object model.

How can i achieve this in rajawali?